# Visual Studio Code Breakpoints out of sync

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-code

I have a few new `.cs` files added into my project and when I try to add a breakpoint in Visual Studio Code, I get a grayed out breakpoint that says `No symbols have been loaded for this document`. If I add a breakpoint to an existing file, the breakpoint will show up red and somewhat work. It'll stop there, but it looks like its out of sync. Stepping through the code does not match with the line the debugger is currently at.

Comment: Do a clean/rebuild. Are you running in `DEBUG` or `RELEASE` mode?

Comment: I'm running in  `DEBUG`. How do I do a clean/rebuild? Is it `dotnet restore` ? I've also tried restarting my computer as well.

Comment: On the Solution in the Solution Explorer - Right Click and Select Clean.. Once that is done - Right Click and Build. Also try put breakpoints from the main() method flow until your breakpoint location.

Answer (score 1):

My issue was that the laungh.json's `program` property had to be fixed to point to the new .dll file. I did a migration from 1.1.4 to 2.0.0 so it was still pointing at the old one.